# Добавление значения к SPAN при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: html

http://jsfiddle.net/u7g189t5/12/

Как сделать так, чтобы, к примеру, при нажатии на кнопку 5 ко всем оценкам добавлялась ещё одна пятёрка? Так должно быть со всеми кнопками. Но должна прибавляться не просто цифра 5, а вот такой код:

```
<span class="five"><span style="font-size: 5px;">&nbsp;</span>5<span style="font-size: 5px;">&nbsp;</span></span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Проверяйте](http://jsfiddle.net/u7g189t5/13/)

HTML

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
    <tbody>
        <tr height="40">
            <td><span>Оценки:</span></td>
            <td width="100" id="vote"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<div id="controls">
    <input type="button" value="1">
    <input type="button" value="2">
    <input type="button" value="3">
    <input type="button" value="4">
   <input type="button" value="5">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.five {
font-size: 16px;
color: #FFFFFF;
background-color: #299900;
font-family: Arial Black;
font-weight: bold;
   margin: 0 2px;
}

#controls {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var $vote= $('#vote');
   $('#controls').click(function(index){        
      $vote.append('<span class="five">' + index.target.value + '</span>');    
    });
});
```

Comment: Спасибо большое Вам! Это мне и было нужно!